# What is 'Dvn2' stand for?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I started a regtest bitcoin network. Then I found most of my UTXOs are sending to a bitcoin address 'msvXYdtdhgWefyKPym2HnSmTUkxUsiDvn2'. The address is belongs to account 'Dvn2'. What is 'Dvn2' stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. Account names don't mean anything. You must have given it that name.

There is no relation between the address and the account name. I assume you accidentally called an RPC passing Dvn2 as name.